# Why doesn't Vlad's Tides of Blood proc spell vamp?

Tags: league-of-legends

While playing Vlad today, I noticed "Tides of Blood" doesn't proc spell vamp.  The ability does magic damage; why doesn't it absorb health?

Edit:
I was playing a bot game with around 600 AP, a Spirit Visage, and a Will of the Ancients.  I used Tides of Blood while surrounded by 10+ minions and noticed no spell vamp.  Magic dmg should have been ~450 to each minion, so 450 * (.25*.33) = ~37, not counting spirit visage.

It's possible I just didn't do enough damage to trigger the floating text, but I started watching my health bar to see.  It's difficult to tell since Tides of Blood damages Vlad when cast, but I still should have been gaining 300+ health.

**UPDATE**

It was late when I posted this, and I must have made a mistake.  I was able to confirm last night that Tides of Blood does proc spell vamp.

Side note, I often noticed only 1 green number pop when I got high enough.  It seems they've combined the floating text into one number, making it easier to see how much health he gets back!

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't proc spelvamp? Because i kind of remember it differently O.o

Comment: Just played a game, definitely no spell vamp.  Maybe it's a bug from the recent patch?

Comment: I'm going to go check it out tonight then

Comment: @Rafael: I remember it as proccing spellvamp myself...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spell vamp / Life steal and AD scaling abilities](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24546/spell-vamp-life-steal-and-ad-scaling-abilities)

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes, your link doesn't apply as Tides of Blood doesn't apply on-hit effects.

Comment: Hmmm just curious were you full health or near full when you tested? I notice that the number don't show up when I am near full health. But numbers start showing up when i am lower health.

Comment: I was at about 1/4 health, and tried to heal on a huge wave of minions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work, but probably you cannot see it because the numbers are too low to break the threshold for spell vamp visual effect. More details on this [forum discussion](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=247034).

Comment: Good reference, but I think I did enough damage to trigger it.  I'll retest tonight.

Comment: *AND* Tides of Blood has a health cost to begin with. *AND* it gets 1/3 the spell vamp because it's an AoE spell.

Comment: Ya, running the numbers surprised me.  I knew it would do reduced damage, I just didn't realize HOW reduced.